# Minimum db level of WIFI to communicate with Server in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

i want to send the data to server from an android app. some times i cant able to sync the whole data to server i think because of wifi db level if so what is the minimum db level can i use to start the sync. can anyone please explain me in that.

To get the db of the wifi i am using the following code

```
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        List<ScanResult> scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                        for (int i = 0; i < scanResult.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("scanResult", "Speed of wifi"+scanResult.get(i).level);//The db level of signal 
                        }
                    return info.isConnected();
```

Comment: Why do you worry about the db level as a programmer you just be able to sync your data when there is a network.

Comment: "Speed of wifi"  ????

Comment: even though the network is available i can sync only some data to server not whole... @DegenSharew

Comment: @greenapps i will post the speed of wifi...

Comment: What are you going to do after knowing the speed of the WiFi? Do you have the power of upgrading the speed?